# Change variables in drivers with a Python script?

Tags: python, scripting, drivers

I have a group of 108 light objects with emission channels. (Because this is Eevee they aren't actual light sources but just pretty props.) I want to be able to control both the brightness and color of the emission so I can do cool synchronized effects. I set this up with a unique material for each "light", and 2 empties for each light driving the emission color and brightness. This was a pain to set up (that's 216 empties and 216 drivers) but it works.

But as I begin to animate it, I realize I SHOULD have used an armature of control bones instead of empties. That way I can animate all the lights in a single NLA strip, instead of with 216 different objects. I can make an armature of bones easy enough, but it's changing all those drivers that depresses me.

My question is, is there a somewhat easy way to change all 216 drivers so they point to bones instead of empties, without manually inputting each new variable? The bones can certainly have the same names as the existing empties. I can probably grind it out in a couple hours but I'm betting  that if I was clever with Python I could speed this up and maybe learn a couple things. Thanks!